# Не могу понять ошибку в linq запросе c#

Tags: c#, linq

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы результатом выполнения linq-запроса был массив слов, в которых буквы заменены на другие. Должен быть такой результат: "zab" "zab" (т.е. в этом случае каждый символ должен быть заменен на предыдущий).

Код:

```
string input = "abc abc";
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var text = input.Split(' ').Select(scramWord => scramWord.Select(scramLetter =>
{
    if(!Char.IsLetter(scramLetter)) return scramLetter;
                                                          
    int letterIndex = alphabet.IndexOf(scramLetter) - 1;
    if(letterIndex < 0) return alphabet[letterIndex + alphabet.Length];
    return alphabet[letterIndex]; 
}));
```

Что не так с этим кодом и почему он выдает такой результат: `` System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.Char] System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.Char] `` ?

Comment: Приведите пример, что на что должно быть заменено.

Comment: Должен быть такой результат: "zab" "zab"(т.е. в этом случае каждый символ должен быть заменен на предыдущий)

Comment: Мне кажется, вы перемудрили, массив слов можно получить так `string[] words = string.Concat(input.Select(c => c > 'a' && c <= 'z' ? (char)(c - 1) : c == 'a' ? 'z' : c)).Split();`

Answer (score 2):

Результатом `Select` будет `IEnumerable<TResult>` где TResult определяется через выражение. Если сделать селект внутри селекта, то результатом будет `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TResult>>`. В даном слукчаем результат будет `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>>`. Второе выражение можно для понимания заменить на метод:

```
const string input = "abc abc";
const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = input.Split(' ').Select(scramWord => SelectChars(scramWord));   
}

private static IEnumerable<char> SelectChars(string word)
{
    return word.Select(scramLetter => {
        if(!Char.IsLetter(scramLetter))
            return scramLetter;

        int letterIndex = alphabet.IndexOf(scramLetter) - 1;
        if(letterIndex < 0)
            return alphabet[letterIndex + alphabet.Length];

        return alphabet[letterIndex];
    });
}
```

Соответственно, что бы получить желаемый результат, нужно результат вложенного селекта объединить в строку(через `String.Concat`), а результат первого превратит в массив(через `ToArray`):

```
var text = input.Split(' ').Select(scramWord => String.Concat(SelectChars(scramWord))).ToArray()
```

**PS:** условие замены не трогал.

Comment: Если автору очевидно нужна строка на выходе, то зачем `а результат первого превратит в массив`?

Comment: так вроде нужен `массив слов`

Comment: Да, пропустил этот момент.